# .htaccess: запрет просмотра файлов

Tags: .htaccess

Вопрос очень банальный, но с одним но - мне надо что бы подпапки просматривались, а файлы в папке - нет.

Уже все перерыл - ничего не нашел

Comment: В папке разместите .htaccess с запретом, а в каждой подпапке с разрешением ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В папке разместите .htaccess с запретом, а в каждой подпапке с разрешением.

Или попробуйте использовать правило переадресации в корневом .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^My-Close-Folder(/[^/]*)?$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```